# How to source a file on Perl Debug prompt

Tags: perl

When a perl script is paused using $DB::single=2, is it possible to source an external file from this debug prompt? Something as follows:

< DB1 > source "/home/myworkspace/temp" ;

I have tried this but it does not work. Any pointers or examples for this?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the double quotes and the semicolon. Type directly the file name:

```
source /home/myworkspace/temp
```

Comment: It doesn't work:
DB<5> source /home/mithil/test   

Argument "home" isn't numeric in division (/) at (eval 454)[/tools/workspace/perl/lib/5.6.1/perl5db.pl:1521] line 2.

Argument "source" isn't numeric in division (/) at (eval 454)[/tools/workspace/perl/lib/5.6.1/perl5db.pl:1521] line 2.
Illegal division by zero at (eval 454)[/tools/workspace/perl/lib/5.6.1/perl5db.pl:1521] line 2.

Comment: Perl 5.6.1? Year 2001? All bets are off.